# Setting additional information for JMS Connection after login

Tags: java, jms, jaas, hornetq

Currently, i use LDAP to perform authenticate via JAAS (configure in HornetQ).
For easier understand, my work flow is like this:

1. Create a connection using *username* and password

> Connection connection = cf.createConnection("guest", "guest");

2. In **login() function** LoginModule, search that username and password in LDAP server for authentication.

> ```
>   /**
>      * Step 2 : Get the ldap information from setting
>      */
>     String baseDN = (String) options.get("baseDN");
>     String ldapURL = (String) options.get("ldapURL");
>     String role = (String) options.get("role");
>     String dn = "uid=" + user + "," + baseDN;
> ```

```
    /**
     * Step 3 : Initialize the context
     */
    Hashtable<String, String> environment = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapURL);
    environment.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    environment.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, dn);
    environment.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

    authenticated = (new InitialDirContext(environment) != null);
```

3. There is a value call userID, 
   **I want to set back to the client so it can get this value**.

I tried to add into Subject method but no effect. So could you teach me.

1. Is it possible to add additional information?
2. How to set addition information that the client connection can retrieve.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: There is no one interested in this T__T